# FIFA 2011, install twice in same PC

Tags: fifa-11

I have installed FIFA 11 on one of my drives and also added a patch to it, I have added a new league to it. I want to play online but my FIFA is no more compatible with online playing, so I want to install FIFA again on my PC but it detects that it is already installed and doesn't let me install the game in a new drive or folder. Does anybody have a solution for me, please?

Comment: Are you sure your FIFA is fully patched? Because if you want to play online you need the latest patch.

Comment: I have the latest patch, the problem is that I have one more league than others and I don't want to loose my carrier

Comment: what patch did you add?

Comment: The patch that I installed is not an official patch made by EA, it's made to add the Roumanian league to FIFA

Comment: I a have the official patch installed to

Comment: So if I understand it correct you cheated? I don't play FIFA, so I don't know what leagues are normally in it. If it is the case that you cheated you'll have to re-install the game.

Comment: It isn't cheating, it's just a patch so I can play on my PC in the Roumanian league and is an unofficial patch. The fact that I have a different database that others FIFA gamers doesn't let me play online. But I want to keep the current installation and install FIFA again somewhere else in my PC without the unofficial patch and it doesn't let me

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the game installed twice on the same computer.  You'll have to choose between having the unofficial patch and being able to play online.  If you have two computers, you could probably do each on one of them.

Comment: I thought of an idea, to make a virtual machine on my PC, teoretical it would be two PC, but I tried to find out if somebody has a better idea

Comment: @cojo Using a virtual machine might work, but generally games don't run very well on virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

its highly unlikely it would work, there could (will) be all kinds of random registry clashes. its possible that you maybe able to get around most of them for just single player but when you get to tools used to dectect things like cheating in online games they are fairly touchy and you may even end up with a bannd online account.

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing one of the two into [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) (I'd recommend the non-online one), that might work.
First, uninstall the current one, then install into the sandbox, turn off the sandbox and then install it again.

Note: I have not tried this, it may not work, get you banned or explode your computer, but I doubt it.